# In Ruby, what is "putting" when we command ruby to puts something?

Tags: ruby, irb

Say we are in the Interactive Ruby Browser and run:

```
>> sometext = "Hello, Cruel World!"
>> puts sometext
Hello, Cruel World!
=> nil
>>
```

What object is doing the putting? I am sure that having a naked method sitting there seeming to "puts" itself is "syntactic sugar," but I also bet that there is some explicit name for the "object" that is performing these actions... something like Ruby::Self or Self::Thing or... what is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To illustrate in irb:

```
2.3.0 :002 > Kernel.private_instance_methods.include?(:puts)
 => true
2.3.0 :003 > self
 => main
2.3.0 :004 > self.class
 => Object
2.3.0 :005 > self.class.ancestors
 => [Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

As Kenrick Chien said in his comment below, "Kernel is a module mixed in to Object, and it provides a private method called puts. In Ruby, private methods can not be called with an explicit receiver. So when you are asking about what object is doing the putting, it's the current object in scope (self) when you call puts."

Comment: Thank you. Now I am going to have to read elsewhere to figure out what the difference between using . and :: is in ruby. Both `Kernel.puts "Hello!"` and `Kernel::puts"Hello!"` work in IRB. So, now I know what is doing all the puts'ing around. That kind of thing wakes me up in the middle of the night, and I forget it in the morning, "What is 'putting' the string, anyway?" I just wake up confused and irritable and I don't know why :)

Comment: @OswaldRoswell `.` is only used to call methods, `::` can do that too but also access scoped constants. IMO using `::` for method calls needlessly confuses things and should be avoided.

Comment: I agree 100% with @Max.  Better to use '.' and never use '::' for this.

Comment: To expand on Keith's awesome answer: Kernel is a module mixed in to Object, and it provides a `private` method called `puts`.  In Ruby, private methods can not be called with an explicit receiver.  So when you are asking about what object is doing the putting, it's the current object in scope (self) when you call `puts`.

Comment: Thank you for your awesome (!) comment, @KenrickChien.  I have included it in the answer, crediting you.

Answer (score 3):

It is a special object called `main`, which is an instance of `Object`, which inherits `Kernel`.

Comment: Thanks. I seem to dimly recall something along these lines... That one could type something like `Kernel::main.puts("Hello World!")` and that was functionally identical to `puts "Hello World!"` with the "puts'ing" object made specific, but I don't remember the exact syntax...

Comment: @sawa In his example, it would be `main`, but in general it's just whatever `self` happens to be. If you `puts` inside of an instance method, the instance does it.

Answer (score 2):

Puts is implemented in Ruby's kernel. More specifically the IO class where this came from. You can find more about this in documentation: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html#method-i-puts